# Vue Instance Methods return formatted property

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I need to create a method that returns the email formatted to insert as the href value of an anchor tag. So the method needs to return the formatted string the the format: " maillto:youremail@email.com".

```
var facultyInformation = new Vue({
     el: "#facultyInformation",
     data: {
          name:{
               first: "first name here",
               last: "last name here"
               },
               email: "the email here"
          }
     },
     methods: {
          getFormattedEmail: function(){
               return this.email;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: I would personally caution about using `mailto:` links now days (and have for a few years now).  It is supremely easy for web crawlers to crawl websites, grab email links like those, and throw them into email lists for later spam usages and to sell to others who will spam you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
getFormattedEmail: function () {
  return `mailto:${this.email}` // same as "mailto:" + this.email
}
```